# Table Key Gathering from Information Schema in MySQL

Tags: mysql, information-schema

In MySQL I am attempting to use Information Schema to gather data about my tables.  My goal is to select the data in one query and insert it directly into another table for future analysis and processing.

Here is a query that I have written.  Unfortunately, most of the time the pk_length (Number of columns in the primary key) is incorrect, and sometimes the count of keys on a table is wrong too.

```
  SELECT
    t.table_schema,
    t.table_name,
    SUM(k.constraint_name="PRIMARY") as pk_length,
    count(distinct s.index_name) as key_count,
    t.table_rows
  FROM tables t, statistics s, key_column_usage k
    WHERE  t.table_name = s.table_name 
    AND t.table_schema = s.table_schema
    AND t.table_name = k.table_name
    AND t.table_schema = k.table_schema
  GROUP BY t.table_schema, t.table_name;
```

What am I doing wrong that is resulting in incorrect data for those 2 fields?

EDIT: Here is the fixed query, using a subquery.

```
  SELECT
    t.table_schema,
    t.table_name,
    k.pk_length,
    count(distinct s.index_name) as key_count,
    t.table_rows
  FROM tables t,
    statistics s,
    (SELECT table_schema, table_name, count(*) as "pk_length" 
      FROM key_column_usage group by table_schema, table_name) as k
  WHERE  t.table_name = s.table_name 
    AND t.table_schema = s.table_schema
    AND t.table_name = k.table_name
    AND t.table_schema = k.table_schema
  GROUP BY t.table_schema, t.table_name
  LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that:

- When you join two tables on a non-unique value, you end up with all possible combinations of the rows containing the matching fields.
- `table_name` and `table_schema` are not a unique value in `key_column_usage`.

As such, in situations where there is more than one row in `key_column_usage` for a given table, you're ending up with multiple copies of the corresponding row from `statistics`. This is messing up your `pk_length`.

You will most likely need to split this up into two separate queries: one for `pk_length` and the other for `key_count`.

Comment: I was thinking of splitting it, but as an `INSERT INTO <aggregate_table> SELECT FROM` I need all of the select to be in one query.  I could do multiple inserts and then aggregate them, though.

Comment: In that case, how about using a subquery?

Comment: Subquery was perfect.  I have put the resulting query up into the question.

Answer (score -1):

### updated

```
SELECT
    t.table_schema,
    t.table_name,
    t.table_rows,
    SUM(s.index_name = 'PRIMARY') AS pk_length,
    COUNT(DISTINCT s.index_name) AS key_count
FROM
    tables t, statistics s
WHERE
    t.table_name = s.table_name 
    AND t.table_schema = s.table_schema
GROUP BY
    t.table_schema, t.table_name;
```

### first approach(wrong answer)

What about this?

```
SELECT
    t.table_schema,
    t.table_name,
    t.table_rows,
    SUM(s.index_name = 'PRIMARY') AS pk_length,
    SUM(s.index_name != 'PRIMARY') AS key_count
FROM
    tables t, statistics s
WHERE
    t.table_name = s.table_name 
    AND t.table_schema = s.table_schema
GROUP BY
    t.table_schema, t.table_name;
```

Comment: The pk_length is from a different table.  Also, this query would give me a count of columns in non primary indexes, not the number of non-primary indexes.

Comment: @Jericon Ok. I've update my answer. I misunderstood for `key_count`. But, `pk_length` is confusing. I think `pk_length` could be counted as I tried just with 2 tables join.

Comment: @Jericon I have read your revised query using sub-query at this time. My updated query returns same result compared to your query and uses two tables and faster than your query. I can't understand why my answer is getting downvote.

Comment: @Jericon And... I think you sub-query does not return table which has no PK. please consider `LEFT JOIN (subquery) k`

Comment: @Jericon Another problem. `key_column_usage` contains not only PK but also FK. I wonder whether you really want to count FK as PK.